# Data Factory How To Add Template Parameter

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am using the Azure Data Factory V2 and publishing the template to a branch in VSTS.

When I publish it seems to automatically populate the ARM Template and ARM Template Paramters json files with a number of parameters, which enables me to override these values when releasing the data factory through VSTS.

[image: View of VSTS of published files]

[image: View of Template parameters file (auto populated)]

However there is one value which is not automatically being picked up which I need to override. Its on a Linked Service for SQL Server, when specifying a secret name in an azure key vault to specify the password for the user name being used to connect to SQL Server.

Oddly the actual user is being picked up as a parameter but not the secret name for the password.

If there is not a way to get it to be picked up automatically how can I set it to do so manually when publishing

I hope this makes sense and hope someone out there can help or have some advise.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using VSTS or are you using Visual Studio Extension for authoring Pipelines? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-data-factory-visual-studio-extension-for-authoring-pipelines/

Comment: Using VSTS (Now called Azure DevOps). Essentially I publish to a branch in VSTS which I then use as an artifact to release to the actual data factory